# Facing error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError during implementation of nterfaces in java

Tags: java, interface

I am facing the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:" even though I have implemented the interface and classes correctly.

I am not able to understand why is it throwing this error I tried using cmd+ click to check if the functions call are pointing to right classes and everything seems to be ok..

I am trying to learn interfaces callback. And these files are in the same package called Src..

**Stack Trace:
**

```
ankitshw@88665a35e50c JavaCodes %  /usr/bin/env /Users/ankitshw/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-18.0.1.1/Contents/Home/bin/java -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages -cp /Users/ank
itshw/Library/Application\ Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage/1f7cf243dbcc01888351871e74299bca/redhat.java/jdt_ws/JavaCodes_7539afab/bin Src.groceryStore 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Src/Customer (wrong name: Src/customer)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1013)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at Src.groceryStore.main(groceryStore.java:46)
```

**Code**

`

```
package Src;

interface member{
    void callBack(); 
}

class store{

    member m[] = new member[2]; // created an array object of type memeber example : like integer type
    int count =0;

    void register(member mem){ // receiving an object of member class

        m[count++] = mem; // initializing the array object using the same member class object

    }

    void inviteSale(){

        for(int i=0 ;i<count;i ++){
            m[i].callBack();
        }

    }


}

class customer implements member{

    String name;
    customer(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void callBack(){
        System.out.println(this.name + "here and I will come at 9:15 Sharp");
    }
}

public class groceryStore {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        store st = new store();
        customer cs = new customer("Ankit");
        customer cs1 = new customer("Aniket");
        st.register(cs); // I can use the object of customer just because the customer is implementing member
        st.register(cs1);
        
        st.inviteSale();

    }
    
}
```

`